# Если метка слишком длинная, кнопка «Задать вопрос» уезжает вправо

Tags: дефект, метки, дизайн

Если метка [слишком длинная](http://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/123456789-123456789-123456789-12345), то на странице этой метки кнопка «Задать вопрос» не входит на страницу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот и выяснилась причина ограничения длины.

Comment: А она кому-то нужна там?))

Comment: @Qwertiy мне кажется, там должна быть кнопка «задать вопрос по этой метке» — чтобы по ссылке открывалась страница редактирования сразу с подставленной меткой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, интересная мысль.

Comment: @NickVolynkin стоит оформить FR на метемет